# Setting SQL query parameter to Int32 in C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm having problems with some code I'm trying to write. I'm doing something for suppliers orders, so I have a table which is named "encomendas_fornecedores" with a autoincrement field before the key that is the code of sale which consists in a EF before the number(which is a text field).

Here is the code:

```
connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand comando1 = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbCommand comando2 = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbCommand comando3 = new OleDbCommand();
        comando1.Connection = connection;
        comando2.Connection = connection;
        comando3.Connection = connection;
        comando1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO encomendas_fornecedores (cod_encomenda_forn, cod_metodo, cod_forn, total_pagar_forn) VALUES('FO', '" + txtcodmetodo.Text + "', '" + txtcodforn.Text + "', '" + lbltotalapagar.Text + "'); ";// insert into table the values with a FO to cod
        comando1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        comando2.CommandText = "Select MAX(num_encomenda) From encomendas_fornecedores;";// selecting maximum num encomenda so I can isolate it and add to a text before(btw I do this in php/sql no problems
       int  numero = Convert.ToInt32(comando2.ExecuteScalar());//max num_encomenda
        string codencomendaforn= "EF"+Convert.ToString(numero);// sales code completed
        comando3.CommandText = "UPDATE encomendas_fornecedores SET cod_encomenda_forn = '"+codencomendaforn+"' WHERE num_encomenda = '"+ numero +"';";//query that is giving me the problems, it says something like "type of data incorrect in data expression"
        comando3.ExecuteScalar();//giving me error this line

        connection.Close();
```

But now here's the catch the cod_encomenda_forn is text and the num_encomenda auto increment as it is in the sql, and I tried to show the query in a textbox to see if its anything is wrong but nothing seems wrong.

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: Normally Insert and Update fail because you didn't use parameters in the SQL.  When you don't use parameters you are passing variables as stings and the driver in c# then has to guess the type and often makes mistakes.

Comment: Change the ExecuteScalar() to ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: SQL parameters will get rid of errors "something like 'data type mismatch'"  Ticks are not all purpose SQL delimiters, you are converting a number to string with them.

Comment: @DanielA.White dont worry man this is for a final end of course and this isnt even on evaluation so dont worry about that

Comment: @Sparky had it before and it didnt changed a thing

Comment: @Plutonix ok ill look into parametres

Comment: but the thing is it works for me in the rest of the program( mind you not this is tthe only update in the program)

Comment: is one of these (cod_encomenda_forn, cod_metodo, cod_forn, total_pagar_forn)  not a string?  if so that might be your problem and why everyone is telling you to use data typed parameters

Comment: they are all string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"UPDATE encomendas_fornecedores SET cod_encomenda_forn = '"+codencomendaforn+"' WHERE num_encomenda = **'**"+ **numero** +"**'**;";//query that is giving me the problems,it says something like "type of data incorrect in data expression"
```

You are passing a string `numero` to a where statement that seems like it is expecting a number.  As long as it is numeric it should work, but definitely not gauranteed to work.  Second you are passing another`codencomendaforn` string to `encomenda` what is `encomenda` 's data type?

It appears that you are not handling potential datatype differences between your c# code and your SQL query.  In addition single quoting '' around a value in a SQL statement tells the database engines that it is a string even if that is '1234'.  While SQL will automatically convert some values it doesn't always.  In addition c# .net library also looks for some conversion etc. before sending the SQL statement.  To fix appropriately use parameters that are data typed to the database type in the SQL table. To fix it simply in the statement figure out your data types and fix the '' single quotes appropriately.

PS the people trying to help you in the comments were being nice and telling you the professional way of keeping your job in the future when you graduate after fixing this issue.

Comment: I am passing an int aint I? cod_encomenda_forn is text (EF22) is the example of a value i am trying to give it ,num_encomenda is autoincrement.Im gonna try to do that. I know they were , im sorry if it seems i was rude to them , that was not my intent , but im not gonna follow this area to my university